# How to Extend table data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html-table

I have made a table using HTML and with the following attributes:

- The table head contains the date of this month the function to represent the table head is head().
- There are table rows for each name in the names array. The id of the row is the index of the name in the names array.

```js
var date = new Date(),
  y = date.getFullYear(),
  m = date.getMonth();
var start = new Date(y, m, 2);
var end = new Date(y, m + 1, 1);
const names = ["JOHN", "MIKE", "SAM"]; // names array
head(start, end); // function for table head
tabledata(names); // funnction for table row 


//function to make table rows
function tabledata(names) {
var loop = new Date(start);
const table = document.getElementById("table");

names.forEach((item, index) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.id = index;
  const td1 = document.createElement("td");
  const name = document.createTextNode(item);
  td1.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  table.appendChild(tr);
  //I think you can add code here
  
});
}

//function to produce date of this month in th
function head(start, end) {
  var loop = new Date(start);
  while (loop <= end) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    var dates = [];
    dates.push(loop.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
    var node = document.createTextNode(dates);
    th.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("t-head");
    element.appendChild(th);
    var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
    loop = new Date(newDate);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
}

table, th, td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    caption-side:bottom;
}

caption {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 
 <thead>
      <tr id="t-head">
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = table>
     
  </tbody>
  <caption>Leave Report This Month</caption>
</table>
```

I want to further extend the table to have the following added features but I am not able to figure out how:-

- Extend each row until the last column. Having one  corresponding to one .

Please see the tabledata() function in the snippets.

Comment: yes, you can definitely add code where you wrote //I think you can add code here. It's not clear how many columns you want. Do you know? Just add more td elements to each tr to however many you want.

Comment: @Yishmeray i mean loop until the last daye of that month that is equal to number of th

Comment: OK, go ahead. loop until you've hit the last day of that month. Create lots of th entries. Right now in your head function you are creating one th. Make more. You could loop in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date(),
  y = date.getFullYear(),
  m = date.getMonth();
var start = new Date(y, m, 2);
var end = new Date(y, m + 1, 1);
const names = ["JOHN", "MIKE", "SAM"]; // names array
const leaves = ["2020-04-01", "2020-04-05", "2020-04-08"];
head(start, end); // function for table head
tabledata(start, end, names, leaves); // funnction for table row 


//function to make table rows
function tabledata(start, end, names, leaves) {
  var loop = new Date(start);
  const table = document.getElementById("table");

  names.forEach((item, index) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.id = index;
    const td1 = document.createElement("td");
    const name = document.createTextNode(item);
    td1.appendChild(name);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    //I think you can add code here
    var loop = new Date(start);
    while (loop <= end) {
      var dates = [];
      dates.push(loop.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
      
      var td = document.createElement("td");
     // var node = document.createTextNode(dates);
     // td.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById(index); //
      element.appendChild(td);
      if(leaves.indexOf(dates) !== -1){
      td.style.cssText = 'background-color: green';

    } else{
      td.style.cssText = 'background-color: red';
    }
      
      var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
      loop = new Date(newDate);
      
    }

  });
}

//function to produce date of this month in th
function head(start, end) {
  var loop = new Date(start);
  while (loop <= end) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    var dates = [];
    dates.push(loop.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
    var node = document.createTextNode(dates);
    th.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("t-head");
    element.appendChild(th);
    var newDate = loop.setDate(loop.getDate() + 1);
    loop = new Date(newDate);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
}

table, th, td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    caption-side:bottom;
}

caption {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 
 <thead>
      <tr id="t-head">
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = table>
     
  </tbody>
  <caption>Leave Report This Month</caption>
</table>
```